# Accessing a numpy array with an array of indices

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to access a numpy array A using another array B providing the indices at each position:

```py
A = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
B = np.array([[[0,0],[0,0]],[[0,1],[0,1]]])
```

Desired output:

```py
C = array([[1,1],[3,3]])
```

I haven't gotten it to work using np.take() or the advanced indexing.
I could do it iteratively but my arrays are on the order of 10**7 so I was hoping for a faster way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I probably should have insisted on seeing the iterative solution first, but here's the array one:

```
In [45]: A[B[:,:,1], B[:,:,0]]
Out[45]: 
array([[1, 1],
       [3, 3]])
```

I first tried `A[B[:,:,0], B[:,:,1]]`, the natural order of the inner dimension.  Your own code could have saved me that trial.

The key with `advanced indexing` is that you have to create or define separate arrays (broadcastable) for each dimension.  We can think of that index as a tuple:

```
 idx = (B[:,:,0], B[:,:,1])
 A[idx]
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding on @hpaulj an alternative way is:

```py
idx =  tuple(B[:,:,[1,0]].transpose(2,0,1))
A[idx]
# array([[1, 1], [3, 3]])
```